# There is no system images at my Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I searched about that for 1 whole day but there is not a clear answer that fixed my problem.  I want to install system images for Android 6.0(API 23) but SDK Manager doesn't show me any options about that.

- Using latest version stand-alone SDK Manager.
- Tools updated to latest version also.
- Checked all Add-On Sites from Tools tab.
- Started it as Administrator.

[My Android SDK Manager Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewQnC.jpg)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your SDK Update sites, make sure that it contains these entries:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml
```

[image: SDK Update sites]

Comment: After that i started SDK Manager as Administrator again and now all images are listed. Thank you very much.