# Sdkmanager in cmd throws IO exception

Tags: ioexception, android-sdk-manager

I've tried using sdkmanager from command line with the following command: "sdkmanager --nohttps --verbose" but it gives me the following exception:

> Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-desktop/sys-img2-3.xml
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1896)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
> at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:246)
> at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:355)
> at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:65)
> at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:138)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Blockquote

I've tried with the --nohttps option but it didn't work. I installed sdk manager in android studio and the version of sdk is 6.0 .

Update: I found in the Android Studio a package that can't be downloaded from their repository in the "Update Sites" tab from the SDK manager.
[Here is a SS with the SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9p3U.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the Android build tools: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229992980

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue.

Note that running SDK Manager as ADMIN will change your SDK Manager screenshot...

[There is no system images at my Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481705/there-is-no-system-images-at-my-android-sdk-manager)

(well it did for me).

But it did not address the issue fully.  Just some more info.